# render page on phantomjs with cron in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, phantomjs, render

I need to rennder page to img. I`m using phantomjs, childProcess and cron. If you know another way - write it please. In my way i do next, but it works only one first time. Help me please.

This is cron code:

```js
var Cron = require('cron').CronJob;
var i = 0;

var job = new Cron({
  cronTime: "*/10 * * * * *",
  onTick: function() {
    console.log("iteration is ", i);
    var render = require('../tests/initphantom');
    i++;
  }
});

job.start();
```

phantomjs code:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 5000
};
page.open("http://localhost:3000/", function start(status) {
  console.log("status", status);
  page.render('test1.jpeg', {
    format: 'jpeg',
    quality: '100'
  });
  phantom.exit();
});
```

and intiate code:

```js
var path = require('path');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs');
var binPath = phantomjs.path;


var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, '/phantomTest.js')
]

module.exports.rendr = childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("err in childProcess", err)
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for watching! Answer is here:
phantomjs code - the same, but that i`ve got in cron code and it works:

```js
var Cron = require('cron').CronJob;
var i = 0;
var path = require('path');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs');
var binPath = phantomjs.path;


var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, '/phantomTest.js')
]




var job = new Cron({
  cronTime: "*/10 * * * * *",
  onTick: function() {
    console.log("iteration is ", i);
    childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log("stderr", stderr);
      console.info("stdout", stdout);
      if (err) {
        console.log("err in childProcess", err)
      }
    });
    i++;
  }
});

job.start();
```